# Recursive numeric triangle in python

Tags: python, function, recursion, numeric

I'm trying to create a triangle like the following:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
2 3 4 5 6
3 4 5 6
4 5 6
5 6
6
```

Without using while, for in, lists, etc. Just "if-else" cases and recursive functions. I've just learned how to do an asterisk triangle.

```
def triangle(i, t=0):
    if i == 0:
        return ' '
    else:
        print '*' * i
        return triangle( i - 1, t + 1 )

triangle(6)
```

It has the same idea I want to apply to my exercise, but I really don't know how to do with the code for changing term by term and print them all to the right like this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my solution. Note that there is neither `range` nor `join`, which implies `for` or `list`

```
In [1]: def tri(size, row = 0, col = 0):
   ...:     if row < size:
   ...:         num = row + col + 1
   ...:         if num == size + 1:
   ...:             print '\n',
   ...:             tri(size, row + 1, 0)
   ...:         if num <= size:
   ...:             print num, '',
   ...:             tri(size, row, col + 1)
   ...:

In [2]: tri(6)
1  2  3  4  5  6
2  3  4  5  6
3  4  5  6
4  5  6
5  6
6
```

If `range` is acceptable, then here is a short one:

```
def tri2(size):
    row = map(str, range(1, size + 1))
    print '\n'.join(map(lambda n: ' '.join(row[n:]), range(size)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `range()` or `xrange()` to get the list of numbers, and decrease the range with each recursion:

```
def triangle(i, t):
    if i == t:
        return i
    else:
        print " ".join([str(x) for x in range(i,t+1)])
        return triangle( i + 1, t )
```

**output:**

```
>>> triangle(1,6)
1 2 3 4 5 6
2 3 4 5 6
3 4 5 6
4 5 6
5 6
6
>>> triangle(1,8)
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
2 3 4 5 6 7 8
3 4 5 6 7 8
4 5 6 7 8
5 6 7 8
6 7 8
7 8
8
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest something like this:

```
def triangle(i, t = 1):
    if i > 0:
        print ' '.join([str(n+t) for n in range(i)])
        triangle( i - 1, t + 1 )
```

The `range` gives you a list of the numbers needed at each level, and the `t` offset is increased by one so you're starting from a higher value each level you go down.

**Update**

I've just noticed your requirement for no `for in` and lists, which probably makes the above example wrong. So here is another suggestion using only recursion:

```
def triangle(size, col = 1, row = 1):
    if col < size:
        print col,
        triangle(size, col+1, row)
    else:
        print col
        if row < size:
            triangle(size, row+1, row+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

By calling the function recursively You have realized a kind of loop. 
Now you can replicate the same idea:

```
def OneLess(i,j):
    print i, 
    if i < j: 
        OneLess(i+1,j)
    else:
        print ""

def triangle(i, t=1):
    OneLess(t,i)#print '*' * i
    if i == t:
        return ' '    
    return triangle( i , t + 1 )

triangle(6)
```